# Move an image in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I tried to move a ball image in `viewDidLoad` as below. I ran it. The Log showed the x value changed from 160 to 50 as I expected. However, the image on the iOS Simulator is still on the original position from the Interface Builder in which x is 160.  Why?

And how can I move the location of the image before it shows on the screen?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"%f", Ball.center.x);
    Ball.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    NSLog(@"%f", Ball.center.x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `viewDidLoad` add your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    Ball.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` method , since your `viewDidLoad` triggers after the view is actually loaded and drawn on the device , and you changing the image location you should tell your device to redraw the view with a new image position.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

```
1. First check that `Ball` is connected to IBOutlet in interface builder.

2. To change the frame of a UIImageView, I would suggest to use UIView animation 
   blocks for smooth animation effects

3. You can also use `performSelector` and delay the animation to e.g., `0.1` sec etc.
```

Hope these point can guide you to resolve this issue.